# Is there a way to make new pages without manually creating classes for it? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an empty page lets call it "class list" which the user can create a new "class" in the listview by clicking a button and giving it a name and when you click on that "class" it opens a new page with that name on the app bar, lets call this new page the "students lists", now you can create another list in it, and I used hive to store the data.
now the problem is when you create a list of students in the "student list" page when you come back and go to "class lists" and click on another "class", the student list you created earlier will appear for every "class" page.
the reason for this is because I have created a class(the syntax) for student list page and it will show for every "class".
since its the user who creates "classes" and I haven't putted any limitation on it, I cant create infinite classes(the syntax) for the pages created so what can I do?

[class list page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvzh1.png)

[inside class 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT9xl.png)

[inside class 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNuFC.png)

here is the codes:

**the "list class" codes:**

```
import 'package:attendance/data/database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_speed_dial/flutter_speed_dial.dart';
import 'package:attendance/insideList.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class lists extends StatefulWidget {
  const lists({super.key});

  @override
  State<lists> createState() => _listsState();
}

class _listsState extends State<lists> {
  final _myBox = Hive.box('mybox');

  ListDataBase db = ListDataBase();

  late TextEditingController _textController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    if (_myBox.get("NAMES") == null) {
      db.InitialData();
    } else {
      db.LoadData();
    }
    super.initState();
    _textController = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    db.Items.sort();
    return Scaffold(
      body: db.Items.length > 0
          ? ListView.separated(
              itemCount: db.Items.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.school),
                  trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                  title: Center(child: Text(db.Items[index])),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: ((context) =>
                                InsideList(db.Items[index]))));
                  },
                  onLongPress: (() async {
                    await showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: ((context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: const Text(
                              "Are you sure you want to delete this class?",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                            ),
                            actions: [
                              TextButton(
                                  child: Text("cancel"),
                                  onPressed: (() {
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  })),
                              TextButton(
                                child: Text('Delete'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    db.Items.removeAt(index);
                                    db.UpdateDataBase();
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        }));
                  }),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  const Divider(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            )
          : const Center(
              child: Text("You currently have no classes. Add from below."),
            ),
      floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
        animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
        spacing: 6,
        spaceBetweenChildren: 6,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 22, 37, 50),
        foregroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
        children: [
          SpeedDialChild(
            child: const Icon(Icons.school),
            label: "add class",
            onTap: () async {
              final result = await showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: const Text('Add a new class'),
                    content: TextField(
                      controller: _textController,
                      autofocus: true,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Enter the name of the class."),
                    ),
                    actions: [
                      TextButton(
                        child: Text('Cancel'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        child: Text('Add'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context, _textController.text);
                          db.UpdateDataBase();
                          _textController.clear();
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              );
              if (result != null) {
                result as String;
                setState(() {
                  db.Items.add(result);
                });
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**the student page codes:**

```
import 'package:attendance/data/StudentsDatabase.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_speed_dial/flutter_speed_dial.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

class InsideList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;

  InsideList(this.name);

  @override
  State<InsideList> createState() => _InsideListState();
}

class _InsideListState extends State<InsideList> {
  final _myBox = Hive.box('mybox2');

  StudentsDatabase db = StudentsDatabase();

  late TextEditingController _textController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (_myBox.get("NAMES") == null) {
      db.InitialData();
    } else {
      db.LoadData();
    }
    super.initState();
    _textController = TextEditingController();
  }

  void _selectRadio(int index, int? val) {
    setState(() {
      db.SelectedRadio[index] = val ?? 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    db.Students.sort();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.name),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 22, 37, 50),
        toolbarHeight: 65,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            bottom: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: db.Students.length > 0
          ? ListView.separated(
              itemCount: db.Students.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                  trailing: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Radio(
                            activeColor: Colors.green,
                            value: 0,
                            groupValue: db.SelectedRadio[index],
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              _selectRadio(index, val);
                              db.UpdateDataBase();
                            }),
                        Radio(
                            activeColor: Colors.red,
                            value: 1,
                            groupValue: db.SelectedRadio[index],
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              _selectRadio(index, val);
                              db.UpdateDataBase();
                            }),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Center(child: Text(db.Students[index])),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: ((context) =>
                                InsideList(db.Students[index]))));
                  },
                  onLongPress: (() async {
                    await showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: ((context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: const Text(
                              "Are you sure you want to delete this student?",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                            ),
                            actions: [
                              TextButton(
                                  child: Text("cancel"),
                                  onPressed: (() {
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  })),
                              TextButton(
                                child: Text('Delete'),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    db.Students.removeAt(index);
                                    db.UpdateDataBase();
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        }));
                  }),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  const Divider(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            )
          : const Center(
              child: Text("You currently have no students. Add from below."),
            ),
      floatingActionButton: SpeedDial(
        animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow,
        spacing: 6,
        spaceBetweenChildren: 6,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 22, 37, 50),
        foregroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
        children: [
          SpeedDialChild(
            child: const Icon(Icons.group_add),
            label: "add student",
            onTap: () async {
              final result = await showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: const Text('Add a new student'),
                    content: TextField(
                      controller: _textController,
                      autofocus: true,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Enter the name of the student."),
                    ),
                    actions: [
                      TextButton(
                        child: Text('Cancel'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        child: Text('Add'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context, _textController.text);
                          db.UpdateDataBase();
                          _textController.clear();
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              );
              if (result != null) {
                result as String;
                setState(() {
                  db.Students.add(result);
                  db.SelectedRadio.add(0);
                });
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question. But you should try to separate your database logic from the views. You can then initialize your views with extra parameters (e.g. for the students/classes), so that each view can be reused. Keywords: App architecture, MVVM, MVC

Answer (score 0):

From what i am understanding, You will need to connect the student list with every single class separately. To show a quick example.

```
List<ClassRoom> firstPageList = [];

 class ClassRoom {
  ClassRoom({required this.name});

  final String name;
  List<Student> students = [];
  }

 class Student {
  Student({required this.studentName});
  final String studentName;
 }
```

Kinda like this. Then when a new `ClassRoom` class added to the list, Show the name on the list. And pass that `ClassRoom` to the next page.
And on the next page, Use that `ClassRoom` instance, and add all the students inside the list of that `ClassRoom`.

Now for every page you will have a different `class` and for every class, you will have it's seperate `Student`.

After that, all you need to do is, handle the `states` of every class properly. And setup a way to store them properly.